# Open another view within same tabpanel after button click in first panel

Tags: authentication, view, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

I have a Main view in which i create three tabs, on click login tab a login form open
after login success, i need to load another view (landing) in same login tabpanel..I have used the following lines of code to load the view but it doesnt opening it in same tabpanel but loading as a independent view. How to open it in same tabpanel.

Main View of application

```
Ext.define("SenchaTest.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.TitleBar',


    ],
    config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [
            {
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    html: [
                        '<img src="http://staging.sencha.com/img/sencha.png" />',
                        '<h1>Welcome to Sencha Touch</h1>',
                        "<p>This demonstrates how ",
                        "to use tabs, lists and forms to create a simple app</p>",
                        '<h2>Sencha Touch (2.0.0)</h2>'
                    ].join("")
                },



                {
                title: 'Log In',
                    iconCls: 'user',
                    xtype: 'formpanel',
                    url: 'contact.php',
                    layout: 'card',
            id:"loginForm",
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'fieldset', 
            title: 'Log In',    
            id:"submitForm",                        
                        instructions: 'Enter username and password to login.',
                        defaults: {
                        required: true,
                        labelAlign: 'left',
                        labelWidth: '45%'
                    },
            items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'username',
                        label: 'User Name',
            allowBlank:false, 
                        useClearIcon: true              
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        name : 'password',
                        label: 'Password',
            allowBlank:false, 
                        useClearIcon: false

                    },{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Submit',
                            ui: 'confirm',
                        id: 'btnSubmitLogin'
                            //  this.up('formpanel').submit();
                            }]

                    }  

                ]
            }

        ]
    }
});
```

Code for Controller

```
Ext.define("SenchaTest.controller.LoginForm", {
    extend : "Ext.app.Controller",
    config : {
        refs : {
            btnSubmitLogin : "#btnSubmitLogin",
            LoginForm : '#loginForm'
        },
        control : {
            btnSubmitLogin : {
                tap : "onSubmitLogin"
            }
        }
    },
    onSubmitLogin : function(btn) {
    alert("onSubmitLogin");
        console.log("onSubmitLogin");
        var values = this.getLoginForm().getValues();
        //alert(values.username);
        //alert(values.password);

         Ext.util.JSONP.request({ 

    url:'http://localhost:8092/returnjson.ashx',
                params:{                    callback:'callback',uname:values.username,password:values.password}, 
                callbackKey: 'callback', 
                success: function (result,request) 
                {     
                    if(result.status==true)
                    {
                     alert("Welcome " + result.UserName);

                                                          Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('SenchaTest.view.Landing'));



                    }
                    else
                    {
                    alert("Username or Password is incorrect"); 
                    return;
                    }
                    console.log(result.UserName);

                    console.log(result);
                    alert(result); 

                    // Handle error logic 
                    if (result.error) { 
                        alert(response.error); 
                        return; 
                    } 
                } 
            }); 
    },
    launch : function() {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm launch");
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('SenchaTest.view.Landing'));

    },
    init : function() {
        this.callParent();
        console.log("LoginForm init");
    }
});
```

View to load after login landing

```
Ext.define("SenchaTest.view.Landing", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    xtype: 'landingScreen',
    requires: [
        "SenchaTest.view.Main"       
    ],
    config: {
        html: "Welcome to my app"  
    }
});
```

i have used...

```
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('SenchaTest.view.Landing'));
```

to load landing view but it does not load in same tab but as a independent page.
Please Help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The following code allows you to extend Sencha Touch with a 'replace' function that allows you to dynamically swap two view components within the same panel (I believe that is what you are trying to do):
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134909-Replace-component-function&langid=4

An alternative solution (not recommended) is to create a third, but hidden, tab panel ('Landing'), then create and show it on successfully login, while simultaneously hiding the login tab panel.